# Appending multiple videos via MediaCodec - about multiple MediaExtractors and Decoders for just one Encoder

Tags: android, video, android-mediacodec

Currently I'm trying to concatenate multiple video files together, and the easiest way to do that is by using `MP4Parser`. However, with `MP4Parser` one has to make the videos have the same dimensions and framerates, for it is only manipulating the containers.

fadden has said that MP4 supports Variable Frame Rate videos and that `MediaCodec` can generate them, so I'm thinking of using the `MediaCodec` suite for this task.

Assuming that I have 3 videos to concatenate, I'm thinking of having 3 instances of `MediaExtractors` and `MediaCodec` decoders, one for each video, and one `MediaCodec` encoder that will put the decoded buffers into the final video file.

The extractors and decoders will be run separately one after the other, and they'll be fed into the same encoder. However, I'm concerned about the encoder's EOS signal flag.

Can I hold said signal flag off until the third decoder's finished? Should I also use the Circular Buffer for this task?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can  send EOS signal flag anytime you want, as long as you do not send a new frame to the encoder after that. In fact you should not send EOS flag if you still want to feed more video frames

Few things that you might want to know:

1. It is safer to configure second decoder after you release the first one,
   Some devices may not allow you to allocate multiple decoders, especially if you are decoding high resolution video.
2. You should add bias to the presentation time to the second and third video(obviously)
3. Yes, `MediaCodec` supports variable frame rate, but I am not sure whether it supports variable dimension. You may need to do some resizing or cropping by yourself (via openGL rendering)

Comment: What about generating all the necessary `MediaExtractor` and decoder `MediaCodec` pairs at the beginning? For example, if I have to concatenate 4 videos, I generate 4 `MediaExtractor`s and `MediaCodec`s, one pair for each video, make them push the buffers into the single encoder `MediaCodec`, and then run through each sequentially. Will there be side effects like OutOfMemory exceptions if I go this route?

Comment: As I said, you may run into trouble by using too many MediaCodec decoder instances at once, beside, you can only feed frames from sencond video after you finished feeding frames from the first video, ( the order of frames that you feed to the encoder should be in the order you want them to appear in the resulting video ). Or is there any benefits by doing so?

Comment: I did like you said, using the Extractor-Decoder pairs to feed the video frames to the encoder, then iterating to the next video when the first one's finished. mstorsjo said there can be a benefit to running more than one decoder instance at once (like when you want to show two videos side-by-side in the end output), but the code will be a bit more complicated.

Comment: Yes, if you want to show the video side by side, you have to run multiple decoder at once ( it may fail on some device, decoding multiple 1080p videos will likely cause an error for old devices ( unless you use software decoder )).
But if you only want to concatenate it, there is no reason to take that risk.

Comment: I've decided to try creating new instances of MediaExtractor and MediaCodec after releasing the previous ones - the multiple instances method doesn't work out if I have to join more than four videos together. Do I generate the instances within the processing loop, or outside of it?